# Does Avira Antivirus require responding to a UAC prompt for EACH manual scan?

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, uac, avira

Testing Avira Antivirus on a Windows 7 SP1 system.  See [this Software Recommendations SE post](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26566/antivirus-for-windows-to-replace-avast-antivirus-meeting-specific-requirements) for the reasons why.

When performing manual scans with Avira from the Windows Explorer context menu, a UAC prompt appears every time.

***Is this normal for Avira?***

It's highly annoying and disruptive.  I've never seen anything like that in any other AV program.

Is there any way around this issue besides disabling UAC (which I will not do)?

Surprisingly, the only reference I have found regarding this issue is here: https://answers.avira.com/en/question/how-can-i-disable-the-uac-pop-ups-when-scanning-individuall-files-17460 .  No one has answered that question, which was posted over a year ago.

Avira claims over 440 million global installs.  I can't imagine millions of  people willing to click on UAC prompts every time they use the shell extension.  Hopefully people here will be able to state whether or not this is the normal behavior.

Comment: I assume you have contacted Avira to confirm this behavior?

Comment: Yes.  Still waiting for their response.  Given the link provided from answers.avira.com, others are experiencing this issue too, and have been for at least a year.

Comment: Sounds like the UAC is suppose to happen in that case.  Don't expect a response to that website though, contact their support by email, so they have to provide you a response.

Comment: Hard to know.  With over 440 million global installs, hopefully some SuperUser posters who use Avira can post comments or answers.

Answer (score 1):

The Avira (v. 15.0.24.146 currently) Control Center has a way to allow a custom scan without an UAC prompt confirmation by enabling the "Allow all user accounts to start an analysis scan" option which can be found in *Tools > Configuration (F8) > Click on "System scanner" (do not expand)*. On checking the box it gives a warning that this option allows any user to start an analysis on any file they might not have permissions on. Just click 'OK' or close the warning and apply changes.

[Sorry for language, not a native](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNuGN.png)

This is a very late answer, so it might not be useful for you anymore. But I was struggling with it myself (have a set of users I don't want to give admin access to and UAC got in their way to scan a flash drive) and decided to answer this so others with my same problem can find this.

Comment: Late answers are always welcome and helpful!  Thank you!